# Basic Vector magnitudes and Quadrants Question

Tags: vectors

Express in unit vector notation each has magnitude of 17.0cm

A) Vector E is directed 27 deg counterclockwise from positive x-axis

B) Vector F is directed 27 deg counterclockwise from positive y-axis

C) Vector G is directed 27 def clockwise from negative y-axis

I tried it like this:

Magnitude(E) = 17.0cm,                      $\theta = 27^{\circ}$.

$\tan(27)= E_y/E_x$ in first quad

$E_y = E_x\tan(27)$ (eqn 1)

$\sqrt{(E_x)^2 + (E_y)^2} = 17$cm    (eqn 2) sub 1 into to 2

$\sqrt{(E_x)^2 + (E_x\tan(27))^2} = 17$

$2E_x^2  \tan^2(27) = 17^2$

$E_x = \sqrt{17^2/(2(\tan27)^2)}$

$E_x = 23.6 i$ and then I plugged into my $E_y$ eqn and got $E_y = 12.02j$

But this is incorrect, my math and algebra seem to be correct and in proper form. My text book says the answers are: $E = ((15.1)i + (7.72)j)$cm

Comment: How did you get $2E_x^2\tan^227=17^2$?

Comment: Earth to Luke: come in, please.

Answer (score 2):

The mistake appears to be in going from $$\sqrt{E_x^2+(E_x\tan27)^2}=17$$ to $$2E_x^2\tan^227=17^2$$